# Need Mod_Rewrite Rule for Remapping Query String

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need a rule that will transform this url:

/index.php?playlist=9822

Into:

/music_playlists?c=1&playlist_id=9822

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} playlist=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php /music_playlists?c=1&playlist_id=%1
```

Comment: (try leave out the first / if doing this in .htaccess)

Comment: Hmmm.. No luck. I thought it was necessary to use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} before the rule...

Comment: hm, right, I think you're right. Did you try it? I'll edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

That worked. Thank you very much for your help!

One note:

On my development server, the directives worked as suggested. On my production server, I had to specify a full redirect url:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} playlist=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php http://www.myserver.com/music_playlists?c=1&playlist_id=%1
```